# How to get almost increasing sequence of integers

Tags: javascript

Given a sequence of integers as an array,i have to determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array. Example

For `sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1]`, the output should be

```
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false
```

There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to get a strictly increasing sequence.

For `sequence = [1, 3, 2]` the output should be

```
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true
```

We can remove `3` from the array to get the strictly increasing sequence `[1, 2]`. Alternately, we can remove `2` to get the strictly increasing sequence `[1, 3].`

The function must return `true` if it is possible to remove one element from the array in order to get a strictly increasing sequence, otherwise return `false.`

Here is what i have already tried , but it doesnt work for all situations

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
        if (sequence[i] > sequence[i + 1]) {
            sequence.splice(i, 1);
           return true;
        };
        return false;
    };
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve almostIncreasingSequence (Codefights)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017251/solve-almostincreasingsequence-codefights)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer

```
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
    if (isIncreasingSequence(sequence)) {
        return true;
    }



    for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length > 0; i++) {
        var tmpSequence = sequence.slice(0); // copy original array

        tmpSequence.splice(i, 1);
        if (isIncreasingSequence(tmpSequence)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function isIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i++) {
        if (sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1]); // false
almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2]); // true
```

Comment: That's terrible

Answer (score 16):

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  var found = false;
  for (var i=0;i<sequence.length;i++) {
    if(sequence[i] <= sequence[i-1]) {
      if(found) {
        return false;
      }
      found = true;
      
      if(i === 1 || i + 1 === sequence.length) {
        continue;
      }
      else if (sequence[i] > sequence[i-2]) {
        sequence[i-1] = sequence[i-2];
      }
      else if(sequence[i-1] >= sequence[i+1]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This is so far the best one. This should be the correct answer

Comment: Can you come up with test which would break if line `sequence[i-1] = sequence[i-2];` is to be removed? It seems useless.

Answer (score 3):

My Python3 answer:

O(n) time and O(1) space

```py
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
        
    counter = 0
    
    for idx in range(1, len(sequence)):
        
        # n is smaller or equal to n-1
        if sequence[idx] <= sequence[idx-1]:
            counter += 1
            
            # checking if index to be checked is within bounds
            if idx - 2 >= 0 and idx + 1 <= len(sequence)-1:
                # n is smaller or equal to n-1 and n+1 is smaller or equal to n-1
                print(sequence[idx], sequence[idx-2], sequence[idx+1], sequence[idx-1])
                if sequence[idx] <= sequence[idx-2] and sequence[idx+1] <= sequence[idx-1]:
                    counter += 1
        print(counter)      
    # return true if 1 or 0 in counter otherwise return false
    return counter <= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution.

First I look for a decreasing sequence. If none, then return true
If there is a decreasing sequence inside the array, I create two more arrays excluding the two items in the decreasing sequence, and check those two new arrays. If one of them has no decreasing sequences, then return true, otherwise return false

```
function indexOfFail(sequence) {
    let index = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length -1; i++) {
        if (sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1]) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {

    let index = indexOfFail(sequence);
    if (index == null) return true;

    let tmp1 = sequence.slice(0);
    tmp1.splice(index, 1); //remove failed item
    if (indexOfFail(tmp1) == null) return true;
    
    let tmp2 = sequence.slice(0);
    tmp2.splice(index + 1, 1); //remove next item to failed item
    if (indexOfFail(tmp2) == null) return true;
    
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(seq) {
  var bad=0
  for(var i=1;i<seq.length;i++) if(seq[i]<=seq[i-1]) {
    bad++
    if(bad>1) return false
    if(seq[i]<=seq[i-2]&&seq[i+1]<=seq[i-1]) return false
  }
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in PHP

```
function almostIncreasingSequence($sequence) {
    $foundOne = false;

    for ($i = -1, $j = 0, $k = 1; $k < count($sequence); $k++) {
        $deleteCurrent = false;
        if ($sequence[$j] >= $sequence[$k])
        {
            if ($foundOne)
            {
                return false;
            }
            $foundOne = true;
            if ($k > 1 && $sequence[$i] >= $sequence[$k])
            {
                $deleteCurrent = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$foundOne)
        {
            $i = $j;
        }
        if (!$deleteCurrent)
        {
            $j = $k;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged javascript, posting PHP code is not an answer to such a question.

Answer (score 1):

I know post is old, but here is php solution to the problem

```
function almostIncreasingSequence($sequence){

$error = false;
$check_current_again = false;

for ($i = 0; $i + 1 < count($sequence); $i++) {
    $next = $i + 1;

    if($check_current_again){
        $i = $i - 1;            
    }

    $check_current_again = false;
    if($sequence[$i] >= $sequence[$next]){
        if($error){
            return false;
        }

        $error = true;

        if($i > 0 && $sequence[$i -1] >= $sequence[$i + 1]){
            $check_current_again = true;
        }
    }       
}
return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think sequence is not almost increasing if there is more than one number which is smaller than it's previous number:

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
    var found = 0;
    sequence.forEach((el, index) => {
        var next= sequence[index + 1] || Infinity;
        if (el >= next) {
            found++;
        }
    });
    return found <= 1;
}
console.log("1, 3, 2, 1: ", almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1]));
console.log("1, 3, 2: ", almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2]));
console.log("1, 2, 5, 5, 5: ", almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 5, 5, 5]));
```

And even simpler and shorter with array.filter:

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
    return sequence.filter((it, index) => it >= (sequence[index + 1] || Infinity)).length <= 1;
}
console.log("1, 3, 2, 1: ", almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1]));
console.log("1, 3, 2: ", almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2]));
console.log("1, 2, 5, 5, 5: ", almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 5, 5, 5]));
console.log("1, 2, 4, 5, 5: ", almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 4, 5, 5]));
```

Comment: Almost good answer , but it doesnt work for this array ` [1,2,5,5,5] ... the output should be false but it returns true

Comment: is it almost increasing or not ?

Comment: No ... for that array i mentioned in the last comment , it didnt work

Comment: one more test case here. [1, 2, 1, 2] should be false but we are getting the true

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for @kag's test case. Please refer to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Solution of a question:

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  var inc = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    if (sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1]) {
      if (inc) {
        inc = false;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  };
  return true;
}

console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1])); // false
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2])); // true
```

Comment: fails [1, 2, 1, 2]

Answer (score 0):

```
function Test(arr){
    var set_once = false;
    for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i+1] <= arr[i]){
            if(!set_once){
                set_once = true;
                arr.splice(i+1,1);
                i = i-1;
                }else{
                 return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: fails [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 5, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 99, 5, 6], and others

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm:** An almost increasing sequence can only have one number that is smaller than its previous number, and it must not equal than the number before its previous number. Also, the previous number must not equal to the number after the current number.

**Illustration:** Consider the following 4 numbers:

```
a, b, c, d
```

a and c must not equal to each other, so are b and d. We must nest this condition within `(b > c)` condition.

**Actual JavaScript code:**

```
const almostIncreasingSequence = seq => {
  let decrementCount = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i < seq.length - 1; i ++) {
    if (seq[i] <= seq[i - 1]) {
      decrementCount++;
      if (seq[i] <= seq[i - 2] && seq[i + 1] <= seq[i - 1]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  return decrementCount <= 1;
}
```

Comment: It's not fully correct, fails on [1, 2, 5, 5, 5] and [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1] and [1, 3, 2, 1]

Answer (score 0):

```
  static bool almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence)
    {
        int counter = 0;           
        if (sequence.Length <3)
            return true;

        int prevNo = sequence.Min() - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Length; i++)
        {
            if (counter < 2)
            {

                if (prevNo < sequence[i])
                    prevNo = sequence[i];
                else
                {
                    if (i == 0 || i == sequence.Length - 1)
                    {
                        counter += 1;
                    }
                    else if (i > 1)
                    {
                        if (sequence[i] <= sequence[i - 2])
                        {
                            if (prevNo < sequence[i + 1])
                            {
                                counter += 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                counter += 2;
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prevNo = sequence[i];
                            counter = counter + 1;
                        }
                    }
                   // {
                        if (i < sequence.Length - 2)
                        {
                            if (sequence[i] < sequence[i + 1])
                            {
                                counter = counter + 1;
                                prevNo = sequence[i];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                counter += 1;
                            }
                        }
                 //   }


                    if (counter >= 2)
                        return false;
                }
            }

        }
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python3 implementation of the same. took me a while. not that clean of a code
But take O(N) time and O(1) space so that's ok I guess.
In this case, I had used an approach where I maintained a counter variable and a pointer
I increased the counter by 1 each time the sequence was not in an increasing fashion.
and maintained a pointer to the index of the element which was out of sequence.
if the counter had value more than 1 then the sequence is breaking at 2 points and it almost increasing sequence can not be achieved. if the sequence was already in place then the counter would be zero.
the tricky part comes when the counter is 1
here we make use of the index variable which we maintained that is p
if the c == 1 and the index is 0 or the length of sequence then the element which is breaking the sequence is at the start or end which can be removed to obtain an increasing sequence.

and if that's, not the case. we check for the adjacent values and they are breaking any order or not.
if they are not breaking the order return True else its False. Hope I was able to help. Forgive the Bad indentation. I am new to the code editor at StackOverflow

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
p = -1
c = 0
for i in range(1, len(sequence)):
    if sequence[i-1] >= sequence[i]:
        p = i
        c += 1
if c > 1:
    return False
if c == 0:
    return True

if p == n -1 or p == 1:
    return True

if sequence[p-1] < sequence[p+1] or sequence[p-2] < sequence[p]:
    return True
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extremely dirty version of it.
Lately, I've been trying to make solutions that are language agnostic, so that I don't become dependent on functions for problem solving, but learn them later for whatever language I specialize in.

Perhaps one of the dirtiest ways to do it, but time complexity is O(3N) = O(N).
Space complexity is O(2N).

The logic comes from the fact that you only need to check for ONE missing element, so there is no need to do anything fancy, just save the index of that element and check the array without that element.
Because sometimes you can run into another element being the issue (particularly in the case of duplicates), you should save the index of both problem elements.

Again, extremely dirty, but it passes all test cases and time constraints.

```
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
   let wrongindex = 0;
   let nextwrongindex = 0;
   for(let i = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i++){
      if(sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1]){
          wrongindex = i;
          nextwrongindex = i+1;
      }
   }
   let newArr = [];
   let newArr2 = [];
   for(let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++){
    if(i != wrongindex){
     newArr.push(sequence[i]);
    }
   }
   
   for(let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++){
    if(i != nextwrongindex){
     newArr2.push(sequence[i]);
    }
   }
   
   let isincreasingcount = 0;;
   
   for(let i = 0; i < newArr.length - 1; i++){
     if(newArr[i] >= newArr[i+1]){
         isincreasingcount++;
     }
   }
   
   for(let i = 0; i < newArr2.length -1; i++){
     if(newArr2[i] >= newArr2[i+1]){
         isincreasingcount++;
     }
   }
   if(isincreasingcount > 1){
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- $sequence = [0, -2, 6, 8] (Expected Output: *true*)
- $sequence = [123, -17, -5, 1, 2, 12, 41, 45] (Expected Output:
  *true*)
- $sequence = [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1] (Expected Output: *false*)
- $sequence = [3, 5, 62, 98, 3] (Expected Output: *true*)
- $sequence = [40, 49, 63, 10, 22, 30] (Expected Output: *false*)

This `almostIncreasingSequence` function will return the given `Array` is Increasing Sequence or not.
You can try the above array examples.

```
print_r(almostIncreasingSequence($sequence));

function almostIncreasingSequence($sequence){

$found = 0;
$status = true;
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($sequence);$i++) {
  if(($sequence[$i] <= @$sequence[$i-1]) && isset($sequence[$i-1])) {
    $found++;
    if($found > 1) $status = false; 
    if($sequence[$i] <= $sequence[$i-2] && $sequence[$i+1] <= $sequence[$i-1] && isset($sequence[$i+1])) $status = false;
  }      
}
return (($status == 0) ? $status : true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the diversity. That's how I solved it.

```
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {

    let failsSeq = new Array(sequence.length).fill(0);

    for(let i=0; i<sequence.length; i++) {
        if (sequence[i+1] && sequence[i] >= sequence[i+1]) {
            failsSeq[i] += 1;
            if (sequence[i+2] && sequence[i] >= sequence[i+2]) {
                failsSeq[i] += 1;
            }
            if (sequence[i-1] && sequence[i+1] && sequence[i-1]>=sequence[i+1]) {
                failsSeq[i] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    const failsTotal = failsSeq.reduce( (acc, currValue) => acc + currValue);
    const failSingle = failsSeq.filter( (item) => item >= 2 ).length;
    
   
    if (failSingle === 1 && failsTotal === 2) {
        return true;
    }
    
    return failsTotal > 1 ? false : true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

for eg 1,2,[5,3],6

We can solve this by 2 pointers, p2 will be ahead of p1 by 1 at the beginning. Once we found that, from the eg, 5 > 3, we need to skip each and check if the sequence is still valid, for that reason we call increasingSeq(), and skip 5 by (p1 -1). Then we skip 3 by (p2 + 1).

Once we skip those we start comparing the sequence again.

```
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
    if (sequence.length < 2) return true;
    let p1 = 0;
    let p2 = 1;

    while(p2 < sequence.length) {
        if (sequence[p1] >= sequence[p2]) {
            const a = increasingSeq(sequence, p1 - 1, p2);
            const b = increasingSeq(sequence, p1, p2 +1 )
            return a || b
        }
        p1 = p2;
        p2++
    }
    return true;
}

function increasingSeq(sequence, p1, p2) {
    while(p2 < sequence.length) {
        if (sequence[p1] >= sequence[p2]) return false;
        p1 = p2;
        p2++
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) {
int n = sequence.length;
if (n == 2)
{
    return true;
}
int count = 0;
boolean result = true;
for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i++)
{

    if (sequence[i] >= sequence[i+1])
    {
        count++;
        if (i != 0 && sequence[i-1] >= sequence[i+1])
        {
            result = false;
        }
        if (i < n-2 && sequence[i] < sequence[i+2])
        {
            result = true;
        }
        if (i == n - 2)
        {
            result = true;
        }
    }              
}
return (count < 2 && result);
```

}

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete working solution:

```
function almostIncreasingSequence($s) 
{
  $bad=0;
  
  for($i=1;$i<count($s);$i++)
  {
      if($s[$i]<=$s[$i-1]) $bad++;
  
      if($bad>1) return false;
      
      if(isset($s[$i+1]) && isset($s[$i-2]) && $s[$i]<=$s[$i-2] && $s[$i+1]<=$s[$i-1]) return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my optimized solution with python:

```
def solution(sequence):
    if len(sequence) > 2:
        for i in range(len(sequence)-1):
            if sequence[i]>sequence[i+1]:
                news = sequence[:i]+sequence[i+1:]
                if news == sorted(news) and len(set(news)) == len(news):
                    return True
                else:
                    news = sequence[:i+1]+sequence[i+2:]
                    if news == sorted(news) and len(set(news)) == len(news):
                        return True
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: This solution doesn't appear to be correct.  Any sequence that is already increasing (example `[1, 2, 3, 4]`) or which contains a single duplicate value, `[1, 2, 2, 3]`, returns `False`

Answer (score 0):

I've checked out that most proposals fails with the new tests added to codeSignal. My approach is not quite optimal but it's easy to understand.

First, I store into a hashmap the problematic indexes (the current and the previous one). After that you can run simulations of the array without the problematic items. It just simply minimizes the brute force approach and it passes all the test even with high amount of items.

Time complexity: O(N+N)
Space complexity: O(1)

Tests passed: 38/38.
Sample tests:
19/19
Hidden tests:
19/19
Score:
300/300

Edited: I added a "break" after first problematic number encountered in order to just handle the first issue. So time complexity now is better.

```
bool almostIncreasingSequence(vector<int> sequence) {
    int length = sequence.size();
    if (length < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    
    // Store invalid indexes
    unordered_map<int, int> m;
    for(int i=1;i<length;++i) {        
        if (sequence[i-1] >= sequence[i]) {
            m[i-1]++;
            m[i]++;
            break; // new added
        }
    }
    // Scan invalid indexes
    for(auto it : m) {
        int prev = -1;
        int numInvalid = 0;
        const int id = it.first;

        // Simulate
        for(int i=0;i<length;++i) {
            if (id!=i) { // Do not add the problematic one
                if (prev != -1 && prev >= sequence[i]) {
                    ++numInvalid;
                    break;
                }
                prev = sequence[i];
            }
        }
        if (numInvalid == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my PHP solution:**

```
function almostIncreasingSequence($sequence) {   
    for($i=0;$i<count($sequence);$i++) {
        $input = $sequence;
        array_splice($input, $i, 1);
        if(count($input) == count(array_unique($input))) {
            $solution = $input;
            sort($input);           
            if($solution == $input) {   
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My javascript answer for strictly increasing sequence.

```
function solution(sequence) {
        
    for(let i =0;i<sequence.length;i++){
        // first iteration
        if((sequence[i]-sequence[i+1])>=0){
           sequence.splice((i),1);
           console.log('5', sequence);
        // check again    
           for(let i = 0;i<sequence.length;i++){
               
           if((sequence[i]-sequence[i+1])>=0){
               console.log('9', sequence);
               return false;
           }
           
           }
           
           
        }
        
    };
    return true
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean solution(int[] sequence) {
    int count = 0;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < sequence.length; i++) {
        if (sequence[i] <= sequence[i-1]) {
            // Increase count if we found a replace.
            // return false if we found more than one 
            // replacements
            count++;
            if (count > 1) {
                return false;
            }
            
            // Make sure you are within bounds of the array
            // compare current index value with with previous
            // two indices.
            // finally compare values before and after the current
            // index.
            if (i - 2 > -1 && i+1 < sequence.length 
                && sequence[i] <= sequence[i-2] 
                && sequence[i+1] <= sequence[i-1]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution.

```js
function solution (sequence) {
  // Make a copy since we'll be splicing away at the array.
  const copy = [...sequence]

  // Iterate the copy.
  for (let i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
    const prev = copy[i - 1]
    const curr = copy[i]
    const next = copy[i + 1]
    
    // If the previous value is neither undefined nor less than current,
    // and the next value is neither undefined nor greater than current...
    if (!((prev === undefined || prev < curr) && (next === undefined || next > curr))) {
      // Splice the offending value.
      const splice = next <= prev ? i + 1 : i
      copy.splice(splice, 1)
      
      // Jump back a spot and continue along.
      i--
    }
  }

  // If we've trimmed more than 1, we've lost.
  return sequence.length - copy.length < 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a generator to yield each possible sub-array and test if any of them holds a strictly growing sequence.

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  function* subArrays(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      yield [...array.slice(0, i), ...array.slice(i + 1)];
    }
  }

  return Array.from(subArrays(sequence)).some((subArray) =>
    subArray.every((element, index) => index === 0 || element > subArray[index - 1])
  );
}

// Example usage
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1])); // Output: false
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2])); // Output: true
```