# How is my almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) code incorrect? [CodeSignal]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've seen some posts about this same question, and I think my logic is pretty much the same as their answers. But I cannot find where exactly I'm wrong here.

- My code first checks the length of the provided `sequence`, if it is 2 or less it automatically returns `True`.
- Next, it removes(`pops`) the first element and check if the rest are in ascending order.
- If the `sequence` isn't in order, it replaces it with the `original` sequence and repeats the second step, but this time it removes the next element (`pop(i)`).
- This continues until there are no more elements to remove, which ultimately returns as `False`
- If in any of the iterations, the list is found to be in ascending order, the function returns `True`.

This is the code:

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    original = sequence.copy()
    if len(sequence) <= 2: return True
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        sequence.pop(i)
        # print(sequence)
        for j in range(len(sequence)-1):
            if sequence[j+1] <= sequence[j]:
                sequence = original.copy()
            elif j+1 == len(sequence)-1:
                return True
        if i == len(sequence)-1:
            return False
```

And this is my result :'(

[image]

I think my logic may not be correctly implemented in the code. But I don't know how to test it. It'd be helpful if you can give me a sequence where this function will give a wrong answer.

---

[Solve almostIncreasingSequence (Codefights)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017251/solve-almostincreasingsequence-codefights)

This is one of the posts I was referring to at the very beginning. It also explains the `almostIncreasingSequence(sequence)` question and the answer explains the logic behind the code.

Comment: That response isn't telling you that you're generating the wrong answer, it's telling you that it's too slow. - try a sequence like [1,2,3 ... 9999, 10000, 9999, 9999] to start to get a feeling for how slow. This problem on 10,000 elements should still be essentially instantaneous (<0.1s) on any modern hardware.

Comment: Yes, It didn't occur to me to read the error message in full! I guess my approach is slow because I'm copying lists at each iteration. Can you give a suggestion as to how can I make it faster.

Comment: Iterate through the sequence no more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to try *every* element. Just find the violation of the ascension, and try to resolve it by removing one of the violators. Then check the rest of the list.

More formally, suppose that the `sequence[:i]` is in the ascending order, but `sequence[i] < sequence[i+1]`. You cannot keep them both; one must be gone. Which one, depends on `sequence[i-1]`.

If `sequence[i+1] < sequence[i-1]`, removal of `sequence[i]` wouldn't help: a violation will remain. Therefore, remove `sequence[i+1]`. Otherwise, remove `sequence[i]` (do you see why?). Finally, check that the rest of sequence is ascending.